# @OneToMany annotation- SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, model

What I am trying to do is to combine `emplid` of `PsStudMajor` into `PsMajor` so that I may just call `PsMajor` model with `emplid` in it.

After adding these codes of annotation into my project, it does not work anymore.
See below

```
public class PsStudMajor {

    @EmbeddedId   
    private PsStudMajorKey id;   

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="psStudMajor")  
    private Set<PsMajor> psMajor;

    public Set<PsMajor> getPsMajor() {
        return this.psMajor;
    }
}

public class PsMajor {

    @EmbeddedId  
    private PsMajorKey id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
    private PsStudMajor psStudMajor;

    public PsStudMajor getPsStudMajor() {
        return this.psStudMajor;
    }
}
```

However, if I comment these codes out, it works.

Here are the attributes from key model

```
public class PsMajorKey {

    @Column (name = "acad_plan")
    private String major;

    @Column (name = "descr")
    private String descr;
}

public class PsStudMajorKey {

    @Column (name = "emplid")
    private String emplid;

    @Column (name = "acad_plan")
    private String major;

    @Column (name = "effdt")
    private String lastDate;
}
```

Here is the error message:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PSMAJOR1_"."PSSTUDMAJOR_ACAD_PLAN": invalid identifier

I have no idea where goes wrong.

May someone give me some suggestions!? 
Thanks!

Comment: Enable `hibernate.show_sql` (*and optionally `hibernate.format_sql`*) to check the query hibernate prepares. This can give a clue as `ORA-00904` stands for non-existent column / alias name used in select query

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond those column I am trying to query does exist and '@column' name is exactly right. Just not sure why it does not work after adding '@OneToMany' annotation. Am I using it correctly? Or are there any conflict between each other?

Comment: I think you are right. There is no column emplid in the table of PsMjor so that the error occurs.

Comment: Another question: I want to query from Table PsMajor with the attributes: emplid, acad_plan, effdt. However, there is no emplid in the Table PsMajor but in the Table PsStudMajor. What should I do to combine them together in the Table PsMajor?

Comment: I have figured out the solution! The way to do it is to put OneToMany on the List<PsStudMajor>  in PsMajor model and ManyToOne on the PsMajor psMajor with JoinColumn "acad_plan". The problem in this case is that I can only mention primary key, which is "acad_plan" column in PsMajorKey model.